# Get where from Codeigniter return Unknown column

Tags: codeigniter

Im trying to get some data based on a WHERE condition from an XML File, but the issue is that on request a foreach condition it return that the column VALUE doesn't exist.

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<COUNTRY>
  <STATE city="NewYork" available="1"/>
  <STATE city="NewJersey" available="1"/>
</COUNTRY>
```

Controller:

```
public function getIdFromCity($city){

        $this->db->select('entity_id');
        $this->db->where('city', $city);
        $query = $this->db->get('cities');
        return $query->result_array();

    }


        $count   = 1;
        foreach ($xml->STATE as $state){
            $data       = array();
            $data[0]    = $state->attributes()->city;
            $data[1]    = $state->attributes()->available;

            if($this->getIdFromCity($data[0])){
                echo '<pre>';
                print_r($this->getIdFromCity($data[0]));
            }
        $count++;
        }
```

The question si, how can i get the data from cities database based in the XML data condition ?

The error is:

```
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'NewYork' in 'where clause'

SELECT `entity_id` FROM (`cities`) WHERE `city` = NewYork

Filename: codeigniter\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query producing city=Newyork
But it should be city="Newyork"
Replace the line `$this->db->where('city', $city);` with

```
$this->db->where("city = '".$city."'");
```

or

```
$this->db->where("city = '$city'");
```

Make sure you have space before and after "=" sign

Answer (score 0):

Repalce this line

```
$this->db->where('city', $city);
```

with

```
$this->db->where('city', $city, TRUE);
```

Comment: `TRUE` is the default third parameter. so it won't affect.